# Expected Array but received ...(JSON)... AngularJS Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, node.js

I'm learning Angular1 from Adam Freeman's ,,Pro AngularJS" book. I've got a problem with building a DeployD app he's describing in chapters 6-8 - it seems like my code doesn't want to read JSON

That's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sportsStore" lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>SportsStore</title>
    <script src="components/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link href="components/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="components/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        angular.module("sportsStore", ["customFilters"]);
    </script>
    <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
    <script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SKLEP SPORTOWY</a>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="data.error">
        Błąd ({{data.error.status}}). Dane produktu nie zostały wczytane.
        <a href="/index.html" class="alert-link">Kliknij tutaj, aby spróbować ponownie</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl"
         ng-hide="data.error">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a ng-click="selectCategory()"
           class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Strona główna</a>
        <a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' |
unique:'category'" ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class=" btn btn-block
btn-default btn-lg" ng-class="getCategoryClass(item)">
            {{item}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="well"
             ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn |
range:selectedPage:pageSize">
            <h3>
                <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
                <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
{{item.price | currency}}
</span>
            </h3>
            <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right btn-group">
            <a ng-repeat="page in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn |
                    pageCount:pageSize" ng-click="selectPage($index + 1)" class="btn
btn-default" ng-class="getPageClass($index + 1)">
                {{$index + 1}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the sportStore.js controller

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
    .constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products")
    .controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.get(dataUrl)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.data.products = data;
            },
            function (error) {
                $scope.data.error = error;
            });
    });
```

I'm using DeployD to build an API, and the problem is that when I try to run my app, the error shows up in console:

> Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received:
>   {"data":[{"name":"Kajak","description":"Łódka przeznaczona dla jednej
>   osoby","category":"Sporty
>   Wodne","price":275,"id":"d9b9e4fcb9df3853"},{"name":"Kamizelka
>   ratunkowa","description":"Chroni i dodaje uroku","category":"Sporty
>   wodne","price":49.75,"id":"3c1cceedb44ddb84"},{"name":"Piłka","description":"Zatwierdzona
>   przez FIFA rozmiar i waga","category":"Piłka
>   Nożna","price":19.5,"id":"447a2079a8488932"},{"name":"Flagi
>   narożne","description":"Nadadzą Twojemu boisku profesjonalny
>   wygląd","category":"Piłka
>   Nożna","price":34.95,"id":"2b2dd597f18bb8a7"},{"name":"Stadion","description":"Składany
>   stadion na 35000 osób","category":"Piłka
>   Nożna","price":79500,"id":"2cfe0f6767240bf9"},{"name":"Czapka","description":"Zwiększa
>   efektywność mózgu o
>   75%","category":"Szachy","price":16,"id":"dfc137db43574b4a"},{"name":"Niestabilne
>   krzesło","description":"Zmniejsza szansę
>   przeciwnika","category":"Szachy","price":29,"id":"e2b644c5091d28ca"},{"name":"Ludzka
>   szachownica","description":"Przyjemna gra dla całej
>   rodziny","category":"Szachy","price":75,"id":"f945806bb011895d"},{"name":"Błyszczący
>   król","description":"Pokryty złotem i wysadzany diamentami
>   król","category":"Szachy","price":1200,"id":"fab242704bb38b64"}],"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:5500/products","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.1/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22data%22%3A%…son%2C%20text%2Fplain%2C%20*%2F*%22%7D%7D%2C%22statusText%22%3A%22OK%22%7D
>       at angular.js:68
>       at angular.js:20392
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15095), :4:388)
>       at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:16203)
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17732)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18006)
>       at done (angular.js:12150)
>       at completeRequest (angular.js:12376)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12304)

I tried to skim through similar errors on SO but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. Did someone have a similar problem?

Comment: The response object in `then()` of `$http` is not the data itself...it has a property `data` that is what you need

Answer (score 1):

`ng repeat` works with an arrays but as per the response getting from the API in `then()` method is not the data itself but it is having a property named as `data` which is the actual array that you have to pass in `ng-repeat`.

So, instead of using `$scope.data.products = data` use `$scope.data.products = data.data`

## **`----------OR----------`**

```
.then(function (response) {
  $scope.data.products = response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows the filter refusing to process the response object instead of the data array. `Expected array but received: {data:[..., headers: ...`

The `.then` method of the `$http` service returns a response object, not data.

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
    .constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products")
    .controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.get(dataUrl)
            //.then(function (data) {
            //    $scope.data.products = data;
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.data.products = response.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                $scope.data.error = error;
            });
    });
```

Data is only one property of the response object:

```
$http(...).
  then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // Handle success
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  }, function onError(response) {
    // Handle error
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

ng repeat and filter works with array, you need to access the **data**

```
 angular.module("sportsStore")
    .constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products")
    .controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.get(dataUrl)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.data.products = data.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                $scope.data.error = error;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular expects the data variable to be type of array.

```
$scope.data =  [];
```

Then try following code:

```
$http.get('dataUrl')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        $log.error('Error ' + status + ' unable to get data from server.');
});
```

Also remember to add to your controller the `$log` to properly display bugs in console:

`.controller('sportsStoreCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log)`